# JNI Mat to Java Mat

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-ndk, mat

I am trying to return a Mat object from my C++ source-code to my Java code. I have the following code:

C++:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL *snip*_MainActivity_grabResult
(jlong matPtr) {
    LOGD("The resultsImg has %d rows.", resultsImg.rows);
    LOGD("The sceneImg has %d rows.", sceneImg.rows);
    Mat* mat = new Mat(resultsImg.rows, resultsImg.cols, CV_8UC3);
    mat = (Mat*) matPtr;
    LOGD("Mat resultsImg is: %d", resultsImg.rows);
    LOGD("Mat* mat is %d", mat->rows);
}
```

Java:

```
public static native void grabResult(long add);
grabResult(m.getNativeObjAddr());
```

However, it doesn't seem to pass through the Mat to my Java as the row sizes of the Mat in Java is zero, where as in the C++ code its a ridiculous number, a number it should not be.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: what is matptr (in the c++ code) ? why are you overwriting the newly created Mat with it ?

Comment: Please see the reviewed code. I'll be honest, I have no idea what I am doing with it - it was something I looked up online.

Answer (score 0):

What is *snip*? The native method may be like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_*snip*_MainActivity_grabResult(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,  jint matPtr) {}
```